# Finding the integer values of $p$ and $l$ for which a function $b(p, l)$ is divisible by $n$

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

I wrote the code in the attached image to find the integer values of $p$ and $l$ for which a function $b(p, l)$ is divisible by 3. Does anyone know of a nicer way to achieve the same result? Perhaps it is possible to eliminate the for loop and solely use functional syntax.

[image: mathematica code]

Also attaching the loop as text in case anyone would want to copy and paste:

```
For[p = 0, p < 6, p++,
  AppendTo[pl3,
   t = Table[{l, b2[p, l] - 1}, {l, 0, 15}] // 
     Select[Divisible[#[[2]], 3] &];
   pStr = StringForm["p=``", p];
   pStr -> t[[All, 1]]
   ]
  ];
```

In the code above, `b2` is defined as

```
b1[k_] := 2^k;
b2[p_, l_] := 2^l (b1[p]^2 - 1)/3;
```

Comment: You should provide the definition of `b2`. Also use a `Do` loop instead of a `For` loop, and use  `Reap` and `Sow` instead of `AppendTo`. Have you tried `FindInstance` like this  `FindInstance[Mod[b2[p, l], 3] == 0, {p, l}, Integers, 10000]` ?

Comment: `FindInstance[Mod[b2[p, l], 3] == 0, {p, l}, Integers, 10000]` gives the error: `2(1 + 3n)` is not a valid variable.

Comment: Where did the `n` come from? `FindInstance` works fine for me using 12.3.1. It sounds like  you didn't run the code I posted but instead were running it in a loop, replacing p,l with some expression involving `n` - please post the full code in that case.

Comment: @flinty I opened a new notebook and only ran the code from the linked screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/qDXGHmm.png

Comment: Opening a new notebook doesn't clear variables - you need to clear the definition of `p` and `l` because if you look in the variable list for `FindInstance` it has replaced `{p,l}` with numbers.